# How to use a std::vector<unique_ptr<T>> as default parameter

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr, default-parameters

### EDIT2:

#### To clarify:

This question originated from a problem that actually had nothing to do with default parameters themselves, but copy- and move-constructors.
I accepted the answer that actually answers the question (so if you are here because of the question title, read it) and will explain why it didn't work for me initially.

### What was the problem?

So the problem, as described under "EDIT:", is actually fairly simple:

An assignment to a class containing a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` will break compilation in VisualStudio 2013 (not tested with other versions) and the error messages are extremely cryptic.

Assumptions in the comments were that the VC compiler had a bug and tried to call a copy constructor which didn't exist.

### Shit, what now?

This assumption was in fact true, but not in the sense I first understood it.

Actually, the VCC *does* in fact try to call the move constructor of `MyClass`, which it does implicitly define. *But*, and this is where the problem lies, it doesn't define it *correctly*:

When defining the move constructor `MyClass(MyClass && a)` explicitly, we can actually imitate the behaviour of the compiler by writing our code like this:

```
MyClass(MyClass && a)
    : foos_(a.foos_)
{}
```

Using this code generates *the exact same error messages* as using the implicit definition, and I guess
you can immediately see what's wrong here: this move constructor actually tries to call the copy constructor of `foos_`, which of course isn't possible, because it in turn can't call a copy constructor for its contents, as those are of type `std::unique_ptr` which *doesn't have* a copy constructor for obvious reasons.

When instead using this code,

```
MyClass(MyClass && a)
    : foos_(std::move(a.foos_))
{}
```

everything works out perfectly fine, because now the move constructor of `std::vector` is called and thus the move constructor for its contents.

### So who's to blame?

#### Possibility 1:

It is in fact a compiler-bug and originates from a template resolving issue.

The compiler wants to implicitly define a move-constructor if needed, and it does so if there are non-copyable types in the class definition and if an assignment to that class is ever made in the code.

If these two conditions are satisfied, it proceeds to define the move-constructor, but now doesn't seem to care about the actual type of the `std::vector` template, only about the class itself, which does indeed define a copy`constructor, so the VCC tries to use it, which fails because of the missing copy constructor in` std::unique_ptr`.

Or, it just skips the definition of the move-constructor entirely and tries to use the copy-constructor, which leads to the same error.

#### Possibility 2:

Something fishy in the Microsoft STL implementation. This is only a clue and I couldn't explain how it worked exactly, but it seems to be a possibility to me regardless.

### How to avoid this mess?

Easy, define your own move constructor as shown above.

---

### EDIT:

#### It seems to come down to one particular problem, the original answer is posted below.

In Visual Studio (2013), create a fresh Win32 console application, don't change any settings and make this your main `.cpp`:

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Foo { };

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foos) :
        foos_(std::move(foos))
    {};

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foos_;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto test = MyClass(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>()); //remove this, and all works fine!
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile it will result in the following error (It definitely works with gcc!):

```
1>  ConsoleApplication2.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(593): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Foo
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory(1486) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Foo
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(592) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<Foo>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<Foo>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\type_traits(572) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<Foo>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector(650) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<_Alloc>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<Foo>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\felix\source\repos\infinite whitewursht\infinitewhitewursht\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp(18) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Foo
1>          ]
```

---

Suppose I have a constructor like this:

```
MyClass(vector<unique_ptr<Foo>> foos) :
    foos_(std::move(foos))
{};
```

With this simple setup, everything compiles fine.
A call to this constructor like `MyClass(vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>);` succeeds and behaves as expected. But I'd like to have `foos` as a default parameter.

*How can I achieve a default value for `foos`?*

This is what I came up with:

```
MyClass(vector<unique_ptr<Foo>> foos = vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>()) :
    foos_(std::move(foos))
{};
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work. I don't know why, it would be nice if somebody could shed some light on this.

Next two tries, which are workarounds, not actual default parameters:

```
MyClass() :
    foos_() //or foos_(vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>())
{};
```

Don't work either. Both these approaches lead to an error message from the compiler and a lengthy output which most interesting part is this:

> c:\users\ *username* \source\repos\myProject\myProject\MyClass.h(47) : see reference to class template instantiation

Where the 47 is the line number of the actual vector definition in `MyClass`:

```
vector<unique_ptr<GameObject>> foos_;
```

So my guess would be that this really is about me doing a huge mistake with the initialization.

Also, I am compiling on VS2013.

The whole error:

```
GameObject.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(593): error         C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory(1486) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(592) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\type_traits(572) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector(650) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<_Alloc>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\felix\source\repos\infinite whitewursht\infinitewhitewursht\infinitewhitewursht\gameobject.h(47) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: (1) `because assignment to unique_ptrs` is absolutely _not_ "impossible"; (2) construction with `=` is not "assignment"; (3) move could be performed

Comment: @0x499602D2 this fella: `Error 1 error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Foo,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0 593
`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was talking about directly assigning, not any magic with `std::move()` but it seems like there are exceptions to everything.

Comment: That error wouldn't occur with a default parameter initialized to a default-constructed `vector<unique_ptr<int>>` because it a move would occur. If you're constructing an instance from an lvalue then an error will be emitted because `unique_ptr`s can't be copied. You'd have to do a `std::move()` instead.

Comment: @iFreilicht: Again, there is no assignment taking place in your code.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I know that I need move for actually moving, and as you can see I do that already in my regular constructor. I also updated the question with more information.

Comment: If you downvote, could you please explain why? I would like to improve my questions as much as I can.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think you got one because you aren't giving us a minimal test example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please paste the entire error dump, from "C2280" until the "MyClass.h(47)"

Comment: @aschepler done. sorry, the int should really be "GameObject" but it doesn't really seem to matter. I'm trying everything right now :(

Comment: [We're still not seeing the same behavior.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2725f53b06627c16) Question: If you use only the code in this link, do you still get the error?

Comment: An error while instantiating `std::is_empty<std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int>>>` looks suspiciously like a compiler bug.

Comment: @0x499602D2 nearly, I found a non-working configuration. as aschepler pointed out, it looks like a compiler bug and only occurs on my windows-machine. I'll post the problematic code in the question, along with instructions on how to reproduce the error.

Comment: @0x499602D2 ok, done. I can't explain it. It seems so simple but VC12 has all sorts of problems with it.

Comment: It's certainly a bug. GCC and Clang compile it without problems.

Comment: @0x499602D2 confirmed it is a bug. I edited my question to explain what happened (didn't want to post it as an answer because it doesn't answer my initial question)

Comment: @aschepler it is indeed a compiler bug, and I found a workaround. I edited it into my question. You might want to have a look at it, it seems like you know more about compilers than me and I don't want to propagate any false information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write constructor overload which takes no vector at all  and initializes your vector by default (To an empty vector):

```
MyClass() : foos_{}
{}
```

Comment: I tried that, and it works for other classes, but unfortunately not for this one. Are there any prerequisites that need to be satisfied in order for this to work?

Comment: Ok, after fixing an issue that didn't have anything to do with the default constructors whatsoever, your solution did work as nicely as expected, even though default parameters now work as well.
I've edited my question to explain what exactly the problem was.

Comment: Visual Studio also prevent compilation when using implicit conversion to unique_ptr see there:
https://code.google.com/p/infectorpp/source/browse/trunk/include/Infectorpp/InfectorContainer.hpp
line 152.. do you have any workaround for that? :(   (same error: "attempting to reference a deleted function" it of course compile and run fine on GCC and Clang)